# Migrating to Java 11 from Java 8. At runtime, Will JDK Internal APIs be accessible from the class files in libraries that were compiled in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-9, java-11, java-module

I understand that any access to JDK Internal APIs from my project's code will be flagged by the Java compiler at compilation. But what about 3rd party library JARs compiled in Java 8.

My understanding is that since they were compiled on JDK 8 or earlier, they will end up in the classpath. The code in these classes can access the JDK Internal API at runtime. Is that correct?

This is from the JDK 9 release notes:
[JDK 9 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8142968)

> All JDK internal classes are also encapsulated at run-time but most remain accessible to applications and libraries on the class path. Specifically, all public classes in JDK internal packages that existed in JDK 8 remain accessible to code on the class path.

So, if my project depends on library X (compiled in JDK 8) that accesses JDK Internals, I should be good right?

Comment: Being specific about which API bothers you as one question at a time would help narrow down the question. As Michael said, since Java-9 until Java-15(in progress) there have been deprecations, abstractions, and removals as well. One would not know how do they impact you unless you call out which one were you making use of.

Comment: Thanks for your response Naman. To be honest, I don’t have an API narrowed down. I just ran a jdeps scan and saw some of the libraries my projects use point to JDK Internals. Based on my reading of the oracle docs, it seems that classes on the class path (non-module path) are allowed access to these APIs. But based on your and Michael’s response it seems that this is not black and white. More of a grey area that needs to be tested case by case.

Comment: Also, I think I over-simplified my question. I will do another jdeps scan and enter the full list of APIs in question.

Comment: Yes, looking for a resolution of those APIs pointed out by `jdeps` one at a time should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you rely on something which has been removed from the JDK, even indirectly, then your code which compiled fine on JDK 8 will not work at runtime on JDK 11.

You rely upon some classes which your code expects to be available on the classpath at runtime. If that expectation is not met, it will not work. Items have been deliberately removed from the JDK; they are not just hiding from the compiler, they are physically gone.

If you can be specific about the internals which you rely upon, we can give you more details about that.

Comment: I am asking about the JDK internals, not the Java EE Modules.The JDK Internals are not physically gone if I am not wrong.

Comment: Michael, the APIs described in this link:http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260